# When I add modules in JavaFX project, I get the error "location is not set"

Tags: java, maven, javafx, module

[Project link](https://github.com/azaderdogan/KutuphaneDemo)  when running the project I get the error "Error: java: Cannot compile a module cycle with multiple module-info.java files: DataManagementWithHibernate, GUI"

I don't know how to build the architecture, can you help me?

**Parent pom**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.azaderdogan</groupId>
    <artifactId>KutuphaneDemo</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>GUI</module>
        <module>DataManagementWithHibernate</module>

    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azaderdogan.GUI</groupId>
            <artifactId>GUI</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

**GUI pom**
How do I run another module with Javafx

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>KutuphaneDemo</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.azaderdogan</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.azaderdogan.GUI</groupId>
    <artifactId>GUI</artifactId>
    <properties>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azaderdogan</groupId>
            <artifactId>DataManagementWithHibernate</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.azaderdogan.GUI.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Database pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <artifactId>KutuphaneDemo</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.azaderdogan</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/src</sourceDirectory>
    </properties>
    <artifactId>DataManagementWithHibernate</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>[Project Structure][1]
```

Thanks for the help

- MainApp
- src
- Database

  ```
  - pom
  ```
- javafx

  ```
  - pom
  ```
- pom

Comment: fxml is not where your expect it to be - check the output path (or whatever its name is when using maven)

Comment: the main project's packaging feature works when jar, but the hibernate module fails